# Error in order(desc(var), by_group = TRUE) : argument lengths differ?

Tags: r, group-by

I would like to solve this error.

My code is:

```
data<- data%>%
  group_by(distritID) %>%
  arrange(desc(var), .by_group = TRUE)


Error in order(desc(var), by_group = TRUE) : argument lengths differ
```

How can I make it work? I would like to order from max to min value from column Var, bur for each distritID.

Thanks!

Comment: What gives `str(data)`?

Comment: `var` is not in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  arrange(distritID, desc(var))
```